# How to include Style option on Text Dialog Editor of AEM Sites?

Tags: adobe, aem

I'm starting to use Adobe Experience Manager (AEM) and I wants put CSS Style on my Text on Site editor, but I can't find the option to style the text. I've followed this [tutorial](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/experience-manager-65/authoring/siteandpage/style-system.html?lang=en#enable-styles-tab-design) but I can't find the path `"/mnt/overlay/cq/gui/components/authoring/dialog/style/tab_design/styletab"` specified on the tutorial. So, how I can enable the Style CSS option on Editor?

[image]

On CRX, there are no `/mnt` path:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The path at `/mnt/overlay` is just a mount point for resources that you'll actually find under `/libs` or `/apps` (if an overlay is present).

You should be able to resolve the resource, even though there's nothing physically present at the `/mnt/overlay` path in the repository. At this point, the [Sling Resource Merger](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/experience-manager-64/developing/platform/sling-resource-merger.html?lang=en) kicks in to find the relevant content under both `/apps` and `/libs`, combine it and return it.

In this case, the definition itself sits at `/libs/cq/gui/components/authoring/dialog/style/tab_design/styletab` (which must not be changed) and there may be nodes under a matching path under `/apps` that overlay or override it.